# How to structurally solve such questions: "30 years ago I had 1/4 of my current age. How old am I?"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the question of course; But I'm getting obsessed with the framework of solving such a questions. I need to know the answer for sure but how can I solve it with knowing anything about math?
I wonder if there's any book to help me?

Comment: let your current age $x$, what was your age 30 years ago?

Comment: If $30$ years are three fourths of my age, my age is four thirds of $30$ years, i.e. $40$ years.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio nice one. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that $30$ years represents $\frac34$ of your life (current age). So $\frac14$ of your life is $10$ years.

You are $40$ years old.

Answer (score 2):

Form an equation :
$$
\frac{1}{4}x + 30 = x
$$
Solve for $x$:
$$
x=40
$$

Comment: Concise and nice. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Just use expressions to represent the quantities, and make a statement as an equality.

Suppose your age now is $x$.

Then your age thirty years ago was $x-30$.

A quarter of your current age is $\frac14 x$.

So the statement of fact for the problem is that

$$x - 30 = \frac14 x$$
Now solve this for $x$ (your current age).